# Is there any hymn or verse for not having any kind of good/bad dreams? How can one skip dreams or illusion?

Tags: shloka, dream, stotra

Is there any hymn or verse for not having any kind of good/bad dreams? How can one skip dreams or illusion?

In Vishnu sahasra namavali I found one

> Om dusvapnanashanay namah

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: It works for me. Chant before going to bed with clean thoughts. I pray lord Narasimha before going to bed. So works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few short slokas which supposedly will prevent **bad** dreams.

From [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Slokas_for_solving_various_problems) page:

> To get rid of bad dreams
>
> To get the effect of reading Shiva Sahasranama **Sloka 1**-*Shivo,
>   Maheswaraschaiva, Rudhro, Vishnu, pithamaha, SAmsara Vaidhya ,
>   Sarvesa, Paramathma SAdashiva.*(to be read 3 times).

It is stated that by reciting the above sloka 3 times one can get rid of bad dreams and also that it is equivalent to reading the Shiva Sahasranama.

> To avoid bad dreams (Chant 3 times before retiring to bed)
>
> **Sloka 2**-*Achyutham, Kesavam, Vishnum, Harim, SAthyam, Janardhanam,
>   Hamsam Narayanam Krishnam japeth Duswapna SAnthaye.*-He who chants “Achyutha, Kesava, Vishnu, Hari, Sathya and Janardhana,
>   Hamsa, Narayana and Krishna, would make his bad dreams peaceful.

You can try  and see if they  work.Also note that these slokas are only for getting rid of bad dreams.

**An update**-

Recitation of **Durga Saptasati** is also regarded as capable of removing/preventing bad dreams.

Another very simple remedy is that by simply remembering about a **Brahmin named Kukkuta** who is/was supposed to live in the southern part of Varanasi city, bad dreams will be converted into auspicious ones.

> Dusswapna Nashaka is also the recital of Chandi / Durga Sapta Shati.
>
> Further it is stated
>   *: Vaaranasyaam Dakshiney bhaagey Kukkuto naama bra hmanah, **Tasya Smarana maatreyna Dussapnah Sukhadob havet***
>
> There is a Brahmana by name Kukkuta in the southern part of
>   Varanaasi whose mere recall of his memory would surely convert all
>   prospective b ad dreams would get converted as propitious dreams!

Source-[Essence of Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php)