# Fear and negative thoughts

Tags: mantras, yoga, puja, sadhana, pranayama

I do everything: pooja and Pranayam, but still I always get negative thoughts.

It always seems that only bad things will happen with me.

I do read sunder kand daily.

Please advise. why it is like that?

Comment: Thanks for the guidence

Comment: It could be that you put too much trust in Hinduism. Try going to a therapist or watch some mindfull video's on youtube.

Answer (score 3):

When you start to clean or tidy up your room, at first it seems that it is getting more messy. You carry on putting everything in their place and carry on with the cleaning, putting all the rubbish away, and eventually the room will be clean and tidy.

Similarly, when you [make ghee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asLxQ0q2Z3w), you put butter to cook, and from time to time, impurities of the butter show up and you need to remove those, and carry on with the fire, then from time to time more impurities come off, which you have to skim off and carry on, eventually you will have pure ghee.

The conclusion is:

We should carry on with our spiritual practices, and count on the Lord to protect us in all circumnstances. Accepting everything as His mercy.

This is confirmed by Lord Brahma himself in the Srimad Bhagavatam:

[ŚB 10.14.8](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/14/8/)

```
तत्तेऽनुकम्पां सुसमीक्षमाणो
भुञ्जान एवात्मकृतं विपाकम् ।
हृद्वाग्वपुर्भिर्विदधन्नमस्ते
जीवेत यो मुक्तिपदे स दायभाक् ॥ ८ ॥
```

> My dear Lord, one who earnestly waits for You to bestow Your causeless
>   mercy upon him, all the while patiently suffering the reactions of his
>   past misdeeds and offering You respectful obeisances with his heart,
>   words and body, is surely eligible for liberation, for it has become
>   his rightful claim.

**Please advise. why it is like that?**

In this material world fear and anxiety are the rule, but this pattern can be broken when we see [everything connected to the Lord](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/6/30/).

> For one who sees Me everywhere and sees everything in Me, I am never
>   lost, nor is he ever lost to Me.

We [have always existed](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/2/12/) and will always exist, so *in a way*, fear is an illusion.
Of course it has its uses - like when you fear failing an exam you should study and prepare more.

[Here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/2/56/) and [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/10/) Lord Krishna repeats these words:

> vīta-rāga-bhaya-krodhaḥ
>
> One who is not disturbed in mind even amidst the threefold miseries or
>   elated when there is happiness, and who is free from attachment, fear
>   and anger, is called a sage of steady mind.
>
> Being freed from attachment, fear and anger, being fully absorbed in
>   Me and taking refuge in Me, many, many persons in the past became
>   purified by knowledge of Me – and thus they all attained
>   transcendental love for Me.

There are mantras you can chant to help you to [counteract\prevent bad dreams](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16088/3294).

There are also some mantras that you can [chant before going to sleep](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34317/3294).

> ugram viram maha-vishnum
>
> jvalantam sarvato mukham
>
> nrisimham bhishanam bhadram
>
> mrityur mrityum namamy aham

'May my head be protected by the moon colored one, who is the greatest among humans. My obeisances unto the ferocious and powerful, the great Visnu, the fiery one, who's faces are on all sides, the fearful one, [Nrsimha](https://iskcondesiretree.com/page/ugram-viram-mahavishnum), who causes the death of even death personified, (or who can overcome death).

You can [hear this mantra here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afKsWzjh2Ak).

Comment: Please Answer This Question too https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40478/how-to-gain-mental-strength

Comment: Please Look at the comment above.